# How to run script on Blender Quit

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to set Blender quit callback? I just need to execute come code when quiting from Blender

Answer (score 4):

You might also try the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module

```
import time
import atexit

filepath = r"C:\Users\pink_vertex\Documents\Blender\log.txt"

@atexit.register
def on_exit():
    with open(filepath, "a") as output:
        output.write(time.strftime("Exit on %d.%m at %H:%M:%S\n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no event handler for blender Quit. See [event handlers](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=handlers#module-bpy.app.handlers)

What I might do in your situation is write an operator and make it an add-on (or add it to an existing add-on), which first runs some arbitrary code, then triggers `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`

quit_with_sidefx.py:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Quit with Side Effects",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 76, 0),
    "description": "Quit blender after running some code",
    "category": "User Interface"}


import bpy


def do_this_code():
    print('this happened')
    pass


class INTERFACE_OT_quit_withfx(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.quit_with_sidefx"
    bl_label = "Quit With Side Effects"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        do_this_code()
        bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(INTERFACE_OT_quit_withfx)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(INTERFACE_OT_quit_withfx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

enabled here

[image]

triggered either via a custom keyboard shortcut (different topic) or simply via spacebar search

[image]

You could ofcourse also add the operator to the *File* menu. Making modifications in standard menus (like swapping out the existing Quit operator with the Quit With SideEffects operator) is not a convenient way to do this and I won't cover it.

Keyboard shortcuts maybe the easiest way to trigger the operator. It's easy to re-purpose the existing *Quit* shortcut by changing the operator path.

[image]

Comment: Thanx, but user shouldn't know about callback executing. He just quit from blender. And i want to run script at this point.